# How to filter URLs and phone numbers from text except if they start with ***

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem coming up with a regex in C# for filtering out all URLs and phone numbers from text except if they start with ***. The stars can also be some other character if it is easier. 
For example exclude filtering of URLs that start with ! or are inside [].

I'm using the **regex.Replace(text, replacement)** method.

```
var rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
rgx.Replace(str, replacement ?? "[ URL HIDDEN ]");
```

So I managed to do it for emails with:

```
\b(?<!(\*\*\*))[A-Z0-9._%+\*-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

My current regex for filtering out URLs:

```
\b((https?:\/\/(www\.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)
```

My current regex for filtering out phone numbers:

```
\+?[0-9]{0,4}[\.\-\/)( ]*[0-9]{3,4}[\.\-\/)( ]*[0-9]{3,4}[\.\-\/)( ]*[0-9]{3,4}(?![a-z]{1,4})
```

I tried playing around with lookahead and lookbehind with many variations and could not find the solution.

Thanks for all the help. Also if you have any other suggestions or solutions that would work better I would be grateful.

Comment: Are you using it inside `Regex.IsMatch`? Please show how you use the patterns.

Comment: I modified my answer. I'm using the replace method currently.

Comment: Ok, I will suggest something that is quite generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the URL and especially phone patterns contain optional parts and even may contain whitespaces, a mere lookbehind will not work, or at least you would have to add several lookbehinds that will make the pattern unweildly.

I suggest using a common approach: match and capture what you need to keep and just match what you need to replace.

Build the pattern dynamically with 2 alternatives: the first matching and capturing the pattern preceded with `***` and the other not enclosed within a capturing group. In the match evaluator, check if the Group 1 matched, and if yes, keep it, else replace the match:

```
var rxUrl = @"\b(https?://(www\.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&/=]*";
var rxPhone = @"\+?[0-9]{0,4}(?:[-./() ]*[0-9]{3,4}){3}(?![a-z]{1,4})";
var rxEmail = @"(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+*-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b";
var s = "abc@email.com ***abc@email.com +22 345 456 678 ***+22 345 456 678 http://eee.tt ***http://eee.tt";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, $@"(\*{{3}}{rxUrl})|{rxUrl}", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : "[ URL HIDDEN ]");
res = Regex.Replace(res, $@"(\*{{3}}{rxPhone})|{rxPhone}", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : "[ PHONE HIDDEN ]");
res = Regex.Replace(res, $@"(\*{{3}}{rxEmail})|{rxEmail}", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : "[ EMAIL HIDDEN ]");
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => [ URL HIDDEN ] ***abc@email.com [ PHONE HIDDEN ] ***+22 345 456 678 [ URL HIDDEN ] ***http://eee.tt
```

See the [C# demo online](http://ideone.com/dhSdkD).

See [**The Best Regex Trick Ever**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

Comment: If you need to also replace occurrences preceded with more than 3 asterisks, you need to use `(?<!\*)\*{3}` instead of just `\*{3}`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will implement it and test it. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with a regex, you can also iterate over them with something like this:

```
List<string> origins = new List<string> { "Do I really start with stars?", "***How about me, do I start with stars?" };
foreach (string item in origins)
{
    if (item.StartsWith("***"))
    {
    Console.WriteLine("item " + item + " starts with ***");
    }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("item " + item + " does NOT start with ***");
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Using regex, at a very low level: `^[^*]{3,3}.*`

```
***123-456-7890 (does not qualify)
123-456-7890 (does qualify)
http://blahblahblah.com (does qualify)
***http://blahblahblah.com (does not qualify)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see how could this be applied to finding and filtering out specific stuff from text... emails, urls and phone numbers

Comment: `origins` would be filled by whatever it is you use to get your links, emails, and phone numbers. Once 'origins' has value(s), you check on the values and act on them.